# Validate XML element against schema

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I need to validate a small fragment of an xml file against a schema. Essentially, I'd like to ask the question "Does element X in XML document Y conform to its type as defined in schema Z?" and if not get a message describing why. This has to account for restrictions placed on those types as well (e.g. maxLength, minInclusive).

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not validate the entire document? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm primarily interesting in whether or not a given value falls within the parameters of acceptability. I don't really care if the document is valid. I haven't tried anything yet. I'm very new to .NET so other than poking around the documentation I don't know where to begin.My only idea is to hand parse the schema and pull out the relevant parts. Then I'd check the data against the restrictions and report any errors, but this seems like exactly what a validator would do for me.

Comment: Have you looked at the [XmlSchema class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.aspx)?

Comment: It looks like I could use XmlSchema to search for the type declaration and then do the checking manually (as I described above) but it doesn't seem to have any functionality above representing a schema as an object. Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry. Should have pointed you to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was much easier than I expected. The solution was to create a new schema that contains as its root the one element I want to verify. Once this schema is added to the schemaset, you can simply validate the fragment as you would any complete document.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about doing this from C#, but it's easily done in XQuery or XSLT 2.0. In XSLT 2.0 it's:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="doc('doc.xml')//selected/element" validation="strict"/>
```

and in XQuery it's

```
validate strict {doc('doc.xml')//selected/element}
```

All you need is a schema-aware XQuery or XSLT 2.0 processor that runs in your chosen environment.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, neither of these are available in .NET as far as I can tell.

Comment: There are a number of XQuery and XSLT 2.0 processors that run in a .NET environment, for example Saxon and XQSharp - neither from Microsoft, of course.

Answer (score 0):

A microsoft knowledge article that exactly describes validating Xml fragments. This could be useful.
 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318504